# how to get only the branch of the searched elastic nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

i have a big elastic search nested object.
But when queried for the inner nested objects - the nested queries always return the root.
is it possible to return only the branch of the nested object that i search for?

for example, my nested object:

```
root: 
{
  NestedObjectA: 
    {valueA: 1, 
     array_of_nested_B_objects: 
       [{valueB: 2}, {valueB:3}] 
    }
}
```

so if i search for an object in array_of_nested_B_objects with value 3 - i dont want to get the object with value 2 at all.

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html) in your nested query, to get only the nested object in the result that matched your query

Comment: @eyal gromzin can you please share your index mapping and a complete sample index data so that I can provide a working example of the same

Comment: inner hits is good enough answer, ill do the rest by myself. but is there another way? and is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: @eyalgromzin this is the only way through which you can get the matched nested object in the result, and yes, it is the right way